# Calculating the contour integral: $\int_{|z-z_0|=r}\frac{1}{\bar{z}}dz$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

I'm trying to find out what the following contour integral equals to: $$\int_{|z-z_0|=r}\frac{1}{\bar{z}}dz$$
given that $z_0$ is a point in the complex plane, where $|z_0|\neq r >0$.
Due to the fact that the function is not holomorphic, I'm not able to apply any theorems that require this condition. If I parametrize the contour, I get:
$$i\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{re^{2it}}{\bar{z_0}e^{it}+r}dt$$
When $z_0=0$, the answer is trivial. However, I have difficulty calculating this integral when $z_0$ is any other point. I would appreciate some help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: $\frac 1  {\overline z}=\frac 1  {\overline {z-z_0}+\overline{z_0}}$ and $\overline {z-z_0}=\frac {r^{2}} {z-z_0}$ when $|z-z_0|=r$. Now apply Cauchy's Theorem to see that the given integral is $0$ if $|z_0| <r$. For $|z_0| >r$ use Residue Theorem.

[ The residue at $z=z_0-\frac {r^{2}} {\overline  {z_0}}$ is  $-\frac {r^{2}}{ \overline {z_0}^{2}}$].

Comment: I believe you used the Cauchy-Goursat Theorem to claim that the integral equals 0 under the condition you mentioned? Could you explain how you determined that the function is holomorphic if $|z_0|<r$? It's just that I can't see why separate into cases.

Comment: $r^{2}+\overline {z_0} (z-z_0)$  cannot be $0$ if $|z_0| <r$ and $|z-z_0| <r$: If it is $0$ we get $|r^{2}|=|\overline {z_0} (z-z_0)| <(r)(r)$, a contradiction. So there is no pole in this case. If $|z_0| >r$ then there is exactly one point where the denominator becomes $0$. @Daniel

Answer (score 0):

$$I=\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{re^{2it}}{\bar{z_0}e^{it}+r}dt$$

Put $e^{it}=w\implies ie^{it}dt=dw$

$$I=\frac{1}{i}\oint_{|w|=1} \frac{wdw}{w\overline{z_o}+r}$$

There is a simple pole at $w=-r/\overline{z_0}$, at which the residue is $-r/\overline{z_0}^2$. Using Residue theorem, can you proceed from here?

Comment: Could you please elaborate on how you changed the integration bounds? Because if I plug t=0 for the lower bound, I get 1 as well. This leaves me with an integral over [1,1].

Comment: There is no pole if $|z_0| <r$.

Comment: @Daniel.....I made an edit.  The complex integral is being evaluated over contour $|w|$=1.

Comment: @Kavi Rama Murthy Sir....Yes, in that case the integral is zero by Cauchy's theorem.